# Is it typical throughout Greek islands that guests of one hotel can use the pool of another?

Tags: hotels, greece, swimming

In Corfu, (Kerkyra) you can book a hotel and use its swimming pool. You can also roll up to any other swimming pool and use that, free of charge.

Because you can use any swimming pool of a hotel or accommodation that has one,  you can use the best pools on the island, [free of charge. - back up here](https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowTopic-g189458-i363-k2913944-Swimming_pool_use_have_I_got_this_right-Corfu_Ionian_Islands.html)

I believe this rule is the same on other Greek islands, **does anybody know specifically where these rules apply?** Are there similar rules in other tourist destinations?

Comment: I have not heard of this in any place I've been. I certainly wouldn't assume it's standard practice outside the Greek islands

Comment: Do you mean you haven't heard of it on Greek Islands either, or just elsewhere? @KateGregory

Comment: I have no Greek island experience. I haven't heard of it in the 30 or so countries I've been to, including Europe, North America, the Caribbean, and the Pacific. (In Africa I stayed in hotels that were too far from other hotels for me to even consider such a thing.)

Comment: Hi Nathan, this sounds utterly bizarre.  I have never seen or heard of such a thing anywhere.  You are absolutely sure this is the case in Corfu? Did someone tell you this?

Comment: Hi @JoeBlow , yes, I have visited Corfu several times and we have been able to do this. We usually book into an apartment block, go in that pool occasionally maybe, but there is a huge pool right by the beach that we can use. There are signs in some places but I think a resort rep tells you that you can use any of the pools. I think it's a Greek thing.

Comment: This website confirms as much - although different resort. https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowTopic-g676295-i12966-k8909192-Holiday_in_sidari_2016-Sidari_Corfu_Ionian_Islands.html It says you have to buy a drink, others you don't need to. My question is, are there any general rules and is it just for Greek islands(which ones if so?) @JoeBlow

Comment: That's amazing, thanks for the tip.  Purely FWIW I have never seen this on any of the world's beaches.  Occasionally, partner or just friendly hotels, will allow "pool swapping"; but I've never seen a kind of "altogether" rule.  You learn something everyday!  thanks

Comment: You're welcome, you certainly do learn something new every day! @JoeBlow All the people are really friendly in Corfu and it's across the island, not just the resort of San Stefanos that I visit, They are like one big family - I'd certainly recommend it!

Comment: Edited to make info clearer with a link showing you really can do it for free @JoeBlow

Comment: While researching this, I came upon an description for a villa that was a bit more telling: they identified their bar as "one of the few honest bars". It does seem to be mostly a Corfu thing. For instance, Kefalonia has almost no 'shared pools' listed

Comment: On an unrelated note, when you ask for tap water in Corfu and they bring you this glass of white water full of calcium. Tell them no, that you'd like the tap water that they drink, and point to the plastic water filtering system connected to their faucet, which everyone on the greek islands has. Even for tourists, this filtered water is perfectly safe to drink.

Comment: If you stay in the hotel, you can use the pool. If you are visiting the hotel's bar or restaruant, you can use the pool but you need to order something. Hotel managers and people who work there cannot police or interrogate everyone swimming in the pool to see if they are guests or if they ordered something. My guess is that people who worked there were to buisy to check whether you had a room in their hotel or not. There are rules though.

Answer (score 3):

It is certainly the case in Corfu and also in Zante. Hotels often have a sign outside saying ' all welcome'. I wouldn't say it applies to every hotel but certainly quite a few. The deal is you buy your drinks and food at the hotel pool bar etc.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry, but though it might be common that Corfiot hotels tolerate, accept or even promote the usage of their facilities by non-guests, you have absolutely no carte blanche as in 'you can roll up to any other swimming pool and use that, free of charge'.

You must especially expect restrictions from hotels offering all-inclusive-service, since they might not have any means to prevent non-guests from mooching food and drinks, or from upper class resorts, which with good reasons might want to keep their premises only accessible to their paying guests.

I can of course only speak for the other Greek islands I have visited, but the practice seem to be similar there as well. I've never staid in a 'touristic' area on mainland Greece, so I cannot tell anything about the conventions there.

Comment: Are you answering for all other Greek islands, for all of Greece, or in general? The OP is specifically asking for other islands, in addition to the general. This is not the general practice, for sure, but the fact is that Corfiot hotels do seem to follow this, and so may other islands as well.

Comment: @CGCampbell Thank you for the advice. I've added some more info to my answer.